# IntelliJ project window show only regular files

Tags: file, intellij-idea, project

Is it possible to list only regular files in the project window?
I mean withouth showing directories at all.

I would like to use it with scopes. I don't really care where the files are.

I am using the Community Edition 2018.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a user-specified scope in the Project tool window:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html

Comment: What I meant is that once I have a scope I only want to show the regular files, not the directory structure. Imagine a Java app and I have a scope defined like *.Java. I want to see in the project window only the Java files in a flat structure.